# How to raise the precision of pow in C++ for large numbers (10^19)?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I am looking to calculate `9^19`. my code is:

```
    cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout<<pow(9,19)<<endl;
```

The result has the last 2 digits equal to `0`: `1350851717672992000`. In Python,`9**19` got me `1350851717672992089L` . Seems a floating point issue. How could I raise the precision for `pow`? or how to preform a better precision power than `pow`?

I am compiling with gcc version 4.8.2.

Comment: You are using double. Using long double or long long would work better (depending on the platform).

Comment: use `uint64_t` and write your own `pow` function

Comment: Python has arbitrary precision arithmetic for integers. With C++ if you want that you'll have to use some 3rd party "bignum" library, or create such yourself.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it worked by casting entries to `( long  double)`.

Comment: Unfortunately MSVC doesn't support 80-bit double but using a 64-bit int will give the correct result (not with `pow()` of course).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed a floating-point issue: a typical [64-bit `double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) only gives 53 bits, or about 15 decimal digits, of precision.

You might (or might not) get more precision from `long double`. Or, for integers up to about 10<sup>19</sup>, you could use `uint64_t`. Otherwise, there's no standard type with more precision: you'll need a library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The precision of `double` is around 16 decimal digits.

That means, that only the first 16 decimal digits are exact, the rest of the digits are as good as noise.